# Best resources for Reacjs and Flux

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flux

I have recently started to work with [a ReactJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ReactJS) and [a Fluxy](https://github.com/jmreidy/fluxy).

I would like to know from you, which are the best resources you can suggest about those tools: posts, articles, examples... Any resource that made you feel improved after reading!

It is already more than one month that I am working with those tools, so I am over the first step / hello world application! 
Anyway, compared to AngularJS (that I was using before ReactJS), it is appearing more difficult to find interesting reading online (maybe I am just a bad searcher!).

I think the official documentation is very well done and is more than enough to be up and running but I would be happy to get as more inputs as I can, to get more into the architectural choices behind Flux, the reasons behind them and everything that can accomplish the difficult task to make me think! Also comparison with MVC and other frameworks would be interesting!

Any help will be appreciated,
Thanks,
Luca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find a broad list of resources about ReactJS and Flux here:

https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react

Especially [this part](https://github.com/enaqx/awesome-react#approach-explanation) may help you with the architectural choices and comparison with MVC and other MVC frameworks.

Comment: Well, impressive resource! Thanks! :)